# Create function that accepts function

Tags: php, function

I have a function that runs some fairly generic code that does a lot of work connection to a database and setting up different configuration variables. I have within a couple of if statements of this top-level function code that I run that is actually different from function to function.

This is how it looks now.

```
function get_users(){
  // config
  // set application keys
  // connect to database
  // retrieve user data
  // authentication to foreign api
  if(something){
    // some more red-tape
    if(something){
      //more more
      if(something){
        /* finally the good stuff */

        // the code here varies from function to function
        // eg. get users
        // probably will run: inner_get_users();

      }
    }
  }
}

function get_data(){
  // config
  // set application keys
  // connect to database
  // retrieve user data
  // authentication to foreign api
  if(something){
    // some more red-tape
    if(something){
      //more more
      if(something){
        /* finally the good stuff */

        // the code here varies from function to function
        // eg. get data
        // probably will run: inner_get_data();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

How I want it to work, perhaps using anonymous functions:

```
function instance($inner){
  // config
  // set application keys
  // connect to database
  // retrieve user data
  // authentication to foreign api
  if(something){
    // some more red-tape
    if(something){
      //more more
      if(something){
        /* finally the good stuff */

        Call inner

      }
    }
  }
}

function get_data(){

  instance(function(
    // get the data
  ));

}
```

or maybe

```
function get_users(){

  $var = function(
    // get the users
  );

  instance($var);

}
```

I'm looking for better, dryer, and more maintainable code.

Comment: you might be looking for a callback [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something which PHP calls [variable functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). This works both when `$inner` is the string name of a function and when it's an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (although the manual page for variable functions doesn't explain that).

```
function instance($inner){
  // config
  // set application keys
  // connect to database
  // retrieve user data
  // authentication to foreign api
  if(something){
    // some more red-tape
    if(something){
      //more more
      if(something){
        /* finally the good stuff */

        return $inner();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 You always want to check if function exists before calling it.

Comment: iambriansreed, no, not always. It depends on how you handle errors and your approach to defensive coding. I prefer aggressive coding where you let things fail if you've done something wrong since it's much easier to troubleshoot that way.

Comment: "It's better to ask for forgiveness than permission", @EmilVikström this is a very aggressive coding style, maybe a try-catch block to catch any exception instead use always the set_error_handler function give us more flexibility on coding IMHO.

Comment: Yago, I've not coded PHP in a while now, but this should raise a catchable error, shouldn't it? In that case, catch the error where you can handle it in whatever way you wish, but don't catch it in the library function (I consider `instance` to be some sort of library function here). For comparison, note that defensive programming is often frowned upon in the Erlang community: http://www.erlang.org/faq/academic.html#id56015

Comment: Note that I'm not against catching errors. I'm just saying that you shouldn't code defensively. With that I mean that you don't need to check your pre-conditions everywhere, but let the small parts of your code fail if the pre-conditions gives you trouble. In the application at large, catch and log all errors (preferrably in a single location) and tell the user that something went wrong.